# How to properly use a protocol-defined property in Realm predicates?

Tags: objective-c, realm, nspredicate

I am trying to implement a cache system using Realm.

Depending on classes, the cache should have different lengths. I've therefore defined a `StalenessChecking` protocol:

```
@protocol StalenessChecking <NSObject>

@required
//  nonatomic needed when using a getter
@property (readonly, nonatomic, getter=isStale) bool stale;

@optional
- (void) setStaleness: (NSTimeInterval) duration;

@end
```

and an object:

- Interface file (DziObject.h)

  ```
  #import "Realm.h"
  #import "StalenessChecking.h"

  @interface DziObject : RLMObject <StalenessChecking>
  @property (readonly) NSDate* refresh;

  @end
  ```
- Implementation file (DiObject.m)

  ```
  #import 'DziObject.h'
  @implementation DziObject
  {
     NSTimeInterval stalenessInterval;
  }
  @synthesize stale = _stale;

  - (instancetype)init
  {
      self = [super init];
      if (self) {
      _refresh = [NSDate date];
      stalenessInterval = 120.0;
      }
  return self;
  }

  - (bool) isStale {
       return [[NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:stalenessInterval sinceDate:_refresh] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]< [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
  }

  - (void)setStaleness:(NSTimeInterval) duration
  {
      stalenessInterval = duration;
  }
  @end
  ```

I then call them from a Facade:

Interface:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SDK_Facade : NSObject

+ (void) createDziO;
@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "SDK_Facade.h"
#import "DziObject.h"

@implementation SDK_Facade

+ (void) createDziO
{

DziObject *dziO = [[DziObject alloc] init];
// both work fine
if (dziO.isStale) {
    NSLog(@"Is stale");
}
if (dziO.stale) {
    NSLog(@"Is really stale");
}

// Query Realm for all results less than 2 minutes old
// TODO: -- currently crashes
RLMResults< DziObject *> * dzios = [DziObject objectsWhere:@"stale == %@", @YES];
NSLog(@"DziOs: %lu", (unsigned long)dzios.count);

// Persist your data easily
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[realm transactionWithBlock:^{
    [realm addObject:dziO];
}];

// Queries should update in realtime
    NSLog(@"DO: %lu", (unsigned long)dzios.count);

}

@end
```

I get an ugly crash:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid property name', reason: 'Property 'stale' not found in object of type 'DziObject'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define a Realm model property in a protocol that the model class conforms to. It must be done in the class definition itself.

```
@interface DziObject : RLMObject <StalenessChecking>
@property NSDate* refresh;
@property (getter=isStale) bool stale;
@end
```